# import file to android with a file exporer

Tags: java, android, csv

I have searched around but cant find a solution that fits my problem. I am very new to Android.

Building an app that reads and edits csv files.

I have the app so far reading the csv from the assets folder. This is the code I used for that. The Import.java code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CSVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State>{
Context ctx;


public CSVAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);


    this.ctx = context;

    //Load the data.
    loadArrayFromFile();    
}




@Override
public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

    TextView mView = (TextView)convertView;

    if(null == mView){ 
        mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        mView.setTextSize(28);
    }


    mView.setText(getItem(pos).getName());



    /*mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), getItem(pos).getCapital(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/

    return mView;
}

private void loadArrayFromFile(){
    try {

        InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("states.csv"); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] RowData = line.split(",");


            State cur = new State();
            cur.setName(RowData[0]);
            cur.setCapital(RowData[1]);


            this.add(cur);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

As you can see the inputStream is to the assets folder. I would like to be able to search for the csv file in external storage, like downloads or on the SD card but cant work out how to open a file browser to find it.

Any one able to help?

Thanks!

Comment: Android does not have a built in file browser.  So you'll either have to write one, include one available from someone else, or have the user install one separately and trigger it via an Intent.

Comment: @user2339071 - no, that doesn't seem to be a duplicate, as it covers only the most trivial part of a more complex task.

Comment: Ohh.. My bad.. :P .. Removed it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bigger overview here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

but:

---

Internal Storage access:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

---

External Storage access:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question about file browsing.